Impact of ethanol vapors on surroundings
There’s a popular opinion that ethyl alcohol, when spot-applied to some fabrics or leather, may discolor or damage them.
But what about its vapors? Are these damaging as well?
On occasion, 70% ethanol wipes were used to sanitize hard surfaces and countertops.
I do worry: will its fumes affect nearby furniture or stored in the open clothing?

The alcohol wipes are best used on hard counters as the alcohol can break down certain materials like wood and acrylic. Alcohol wipes are safe to use however alcohol fumes can damage Brain, lungs and intoxicate quickly. H However especially with ventilated area, it is safe to use alcohol wipes unless you are ingesting alchohol. To surfaces, the fumes only show very weak degradation unless you are applying it on a weak surface like wood or you are consistently applying concentrated alcohol wipes on a surface. To nearby furniture, the fumes will not affect it much unless you are putting alcohol on the furniture. So nearby furniture will be safe.

Thank you for your reply.

For liquid ethanol, what kind of chemical reaction must occur to dissolve the dye present in the fabric?

Why ethanol in the form of gas/vapor - as mentioned in your answer - does not discolor dyes in clothes or dry out leather?

What happens to ethanol when evaporates into the room?  —
I found some very brief info, it’s heavier than air so doesn’t rise but lingers above the ground, and over several days oxidizes to acetaldehyde and then to acetic acid (other sources say “acetic acid and formaldehyde” or “carbon dioxide and water”.)

Ethanol like water is polar solvent so it can dissolve dyes. The reaction due to structure and variety of dyes is difficult to write or show. Fumes on itself can't harm fabric and show very weak degradation - it is mostly liquid alcohol.  Ethanol can't oxidize to carbon dioxide and water - this is complete oxidation and won't happen without heat. It might oxidize to formaldehyde and rarely acetic acid but this is weak and only certain instances will this happen. Although ethanol will initually not rise, eventually it will diffuse.

This might be useful   https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75083/can-ethyl-alcohol-fumes-be-suppressed-by-a-household-air-purifier-filter

ethanol oxidizes readily to acetaldehyde and acetic acid NOT formaldehyde. Small amounts of a high MW volatile liquid will diffuse and mix and be effective neutral in small amounts. Larges amounts from a spill of ethanol, freons, methylene chloride, carbon dioxide, chlorine, even boiling liquid N2 will displace air from a restricted volume and be an acute asphyxiation hazard [and in some cases explosion hazard].

Oh yeah I just realized formaldehyde is oxidized methanol

Thank you for your replies ChemLover68 and @jimchmst. Within few days ethanol vapors will oxidize to acetaldehyde and acetic acid. Question: Ethanol, acetaldehyde and acetic acid vapors are heavier than air. Does it mean, in still air, such vapors will not leave any tall container, because their heavy vapors won’t rise high enough?
